# How do OpenGL buffers relate to the VAO?

Tags: opengl, buffer, opengl-3, vao

I'm currently learning OpenGL, but I'm having some problems understanding how the different buffers relate to the VAO. In my following code, I'm creating one VAO and two buffers (VBO for the vertex positions and EBO for the vertex order). At this point, if I understood it correctly, there is no connection between the VAO, VBO and EBO. I basically just created one VAO and two buffers. Now with `glBindVertexArray` and `glBindBuffer` I tell the OpenGL state machine my currently used VAO and assign my created buffers to a specific buffer type. With `glBufferData` I then load my data into the buffers. As I understand it, the VAO is still empty at this point and only gets data loaded into with the `glVertexAttribPointer` function. Now, OpenGL interprets the Data from `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and loads them into the VAO at index 0. With `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)` I then specify that the data at index 0 from my VAO (the vertex positions) should be used in the rendering process.

```
unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

In my main loop, I specify a shader for my triangles, bind a VAO for rendering and then draw the elements followed by swapping the front and back buffers.

```
glUseProgram(shader);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

But how exactly does OpenGL know the order from the vertices? I have only uploaded the vertex position data into my VAO, but not the order(element) data. Does `glVertexAttribPointer` perhaps take into account the currently bound data from the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` when loading data into the VAO? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, OpenGL interprets the Data from GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER and loads them into the VAO at index 0.

No. Well sort of, but not in the way you seem to be describing it.

Most buffer binding points bind a buffer to the OpenGL context. The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point is different. It attaches the buffer to the VAO that itself is bound to the context. That is, the act of calling `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)` *itself* is what creates an association between the VAO and the index buffer. This association has nothing to do with `glVertexAttribPointer`.

This also means that if you don't have a VAO bound to the context, you cannot bind anything to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: I actually misspelled this sentence and wrote `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. But your explanation makes sense. `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not a global buffer of OpenGL itself, but the buffer is bound to the currently bound VAO. The Khronos [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use) also says what you stated. `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`: The indices used for indexed rendering will be taken from the buffer object. Note that this binding target is part of a Vertex Array Objects state, so a VAO must be bound before binding a buffer here.